# Dapper many to many insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

Below is the file I want to insert into SQL, I have loaded into a c# object (MyObject) and I am using Dapper, C#.
My main table is Person ,child table Test and Staging table contains ID,PersonID,TestID composite key

Question1 : I am unclear how to insert the tags into Person, as tags is a list within Person object.

Question2 : How do I fix the below code, as I am not clear how to loop through the entity Test within the for each loop. I was referencing [Dapper many-to-many insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66781724/dapper-many-to-many-insert)

```
{
    "_id": "1",
      "name": "Leiz Gab",
    "tags": [
      "tagA",
      "tagB",
      "tagC"
    ],
    "tests": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "A bsd"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "S Bsd"
      }
    ]
  }
```

My code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cs = @"Server=DESKTOP-FSNG2D1;Database=msdb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            using var con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();

            List<MyObject> processList = new List<MyObject>();
            MyObject obj = new MyObject();           

            obj.A = "AB";
            obj.B = "CD";

            Test tst = new Test();
            tst.Firstname = "A";
            tst.Surname = "Avd";
            Test tst1 = new Test();
            tst1.Firstname = "B";
            tst1.Surname = "Brgu";

            obj.D.Add(tst);
            obj.D.Add(tst1);

            string pINSERT = "INSERT INTO [msdb].[dbo].[AzureBlob] VALUES(@A, @B, @C,@D)";

            string tINSERT = "INSERT INTO [msdb].[dbo].[Test] VALUES(@Surname, @Firstname)";

            string aINSERT = "INSERT INTO [msdb].[dbo].[Staging] (PersonID, TestID) VALUES(@PersonID, @TestID)";

            var res = con.ExecuteScalarAsync(pINSERT);

            foreach (var a in obj.D)
            {
                var testID = con.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(tINSERT, a);

                var arows =  con.ExecuteAsync(aINSERT, new { PersonID = res, TestID = testID });
            }

        }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public List<string> C { get; set; }
        public List<Test> D new List<Test>();

    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

    }

    public class Staging
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public int TestID { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: obj.D is your list of Test, right? So `foreach(var t in obj.D)`?

Comment: Thank you,  tried that but getting below error, it does not let me add to the list at below location:                                                                                                          ```Test tst = new Test();
            tst.Firstname = "A";
            tst.Surname = "Avd";
            Test tst1 = new Test();
            tst1.Firstname = "B";
            tst1.Surname = "Brgu";
            obj.D.Add(tst);
            obj.D.Add(tst1); ```  System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'  InsertRow.MyObject.D.get returned null.

Comment: I don't understand what youre saying. You appear to have pasted code that is already present in the question, into a comment but not explained anything. **Edit the question** so the code is how you have it now and provide an indication of which line gives the error

Comment: @CaiusJard Sure, I have amended the code with you initial suggestion ```foreach (var a in obj.D)``` and tried to run it and I get the null ReferenceException, it basically does not let me add items to the list , can you please suggest how to proceed further. Thanks

Comment: My friend you D list is current not initialized.

Comment: Thank maxspan, I resolved the error now, however no data is inserted into the SQL table and there is no error as well. Something is missing in my code..

Comment: Thank you, @maxspan, my bad. The error has gone however Dapper has not inserted any records into the table.

Comment: @CaiusJard my intension is to extract the primary key value of Table Test: Id that was inserted and use it to load in the staging table. Can you please suggest teh correct way to capture it

Comment: it's an auto number identity field?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, it a unique key auto incremented.

Answer (score 1):

In your MyObject set the list property to as below. You need to initialize you list before using it.
public List D { get; set; } = new List();

Comment: Thank you @maxspan , however Dapper, above code is not inserting any records into the sql table, surely I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your second query:

```
INSERT INTO [msdb].[dbo].[Test] VALUES(@Surname, @Firstname);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

This should mean that your code will received the generated id, and work from there